# Exiting an application when it goes to the background

Tags: iphone, objective-c

When the application goes to the background I need to exit the application. I have googled and found out that I have to set `UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend` to `YES` in the `plist`. But where in `plist` should I add this?

Can someone help me out?

Comment: The answer bellow is absolutely correct. Please change existing and exist to exiting and exit. Probably autocorrect?

Comment: I already have an edit pending for the changes.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Go to the "AppName-Info" plist in the supporting files folder, you have to add 'Application does not run in background' and change it to YES.

Comment: Ok, the first entry in that is `Localization native development region`, and like wise there are many (15). Under which row should i add  'Application does not run in background' and change it to YES.

Comment: Click on '+' and add a new row

Comment: When i click on `Localization native development region` then i see a + sign. do you want me to click `Localization native development region` and then add ?

Comment: Ok, got it, you have to R-Click and then select Add. Thanks